# Extracting last name from a range having suffixes using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of full names in a column like for example:

```
Dave M. Butterworth
Dave M. Butterworth,II
H.F. Light jr
H.F. Light ,jr.
H.F. Light sr 
Halle plumerey
```

The names are in a column. The initials are not limited to these only.

I want to extract the last name using a generic function. Is it possible?

Comment: So the LastNames are `Butterworth`, `Light` and `Plumerey`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following *UDF*:

```
Public Function LastName(sIn As String) As String
  Dim Ka As Long, t As String
  ary = Split(sIn, " ")
  Ka = UBound(ary)
  t = ary(Ka)

  If t = "jr" Or t = ",jr" Or t = "sr" Or t = ",jr." Then
    Ka = Ka - 1
  End If

  t = ary(Ka)
  If InStr(1, t, ",") = 0 Then
    LastName = t
    Exit Function
  End If

  bry = Split(t, ",")
  LastName = bry(LBound(bry))
End Function
```

[image]

***NOTE:***

You will have to expand this line:

```
If t = "jr" Or t = ",jr" Or t = "sr" Or t = ",jr." Then
```

to include all other initial sets you wish to exclude.
You will also have to update this code to handle other exceptions as you find them !

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I made some minor adjustments according to my need and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Remove punctuation, split to an array and walk backwards until you find a string that does not match a lookup of ignorable monikers like "ii/jr/sr/dr".

You could also add a check to eliminate tokens based on their length.

```
Function LastName(name As String) As String
    Dim parts() As String, i As Long
    parts = Split(Trim$(Replace$(Replace$(name, ",", ""), ".", "")), " ")

    For i = UBound(parts) To 0 Step -1
        Select Case UCase$(parts(i))
            Case "", "JR", "SR", "DR", "I", "II"
            Case Else:
                LastName = parts(i)
                Exit Function
        End Select
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Hii Alex,
Can you explain the role of replace$, and trim$ and how they are different than normal functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I made some minor adjustments according to my need and it worked.